# Swift/iOS Parse image from instagram post

Tags: ios, swift, kanna

I'm trying to find the way to parse image from instagram post by link with no login in to instagram.
For now I tried to use [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) but my xpath request dont work.
I have this code:

```
import Kanna

func getparse(){
    if let doc = try? Kanna.HTML(url: URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/p/CL19xB_M7Wv/")!, encoding: .utf8){
        print(doc.title)
        for link in doc.xpath(#"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/img/@src"#) {
                    print(link.text)
                }
    }
}
```

How can I parse it correctly and maybe I can use cocoapod or something?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you copied the xpath from chrome. The DOM presented in the browser gets modified, thats why the xpath query fails.
Use a tool like postman to see the actual structure of the response from your request.

Try something like:

```
doc?.at_xpath(#"/html/head/meta[@property='og:image']"#)?["content"]
```

The image url is the "content" attribute of the meta tag with the attribute property set to 'og:image'.